# WP Query - Show custom posts only if user contain some user meta

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I am trying to make a list of custom post type which going to show all posts but only if author contains custom user meta named "activeacc".

So.. I have thic code...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
    $your_query->the_post();
    $the_title = get_the_title(); // variable $the_title now holds your title
}
```

Is it possible to add to this $args whether the author contains custom user meta 'activeacc'? If not, then do not show this posts (even they have "publish" status)?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach in two steps. First get all the users that match your criteria

```php
$user_ids = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'activeacc',
    'meta_value' => true, // or whatever value you are storing
    'fields' => 'ID',
]);
```

and then run your `WP_Query` for only those users

```php
$properties = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'author__in' => $user_ids,
]);
```

There is no need to set `post_status => 'publish'` since it's the default.

Also would be possible to accomplish the same in just one query with `posts_clauses` filter but I will not develop it here.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/ for all available arguments for `get_users`.